# How to use Selenium to click element inside Java Applet

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I am scrapping a webpage that uses `Java Applet`. This applet generate a select tag and I want to click one of its options.
`Selenium` does find the element when I run:

```
doc_select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('selectClass'))
```

If I inspect `doc_select`, I get:

```
<selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select instance at 0xb5a486ec>
```

And I can see that the driver has found all of the options in the debugger.
However, if I try to select one of the options using:

```
doc_select.select_by_value('9501')
```

It throws me the exception:

> {ElementNotVisibleException}Message: Element is not currently visible
>   and so may not be interacted with
>       Stacktrace:
>           at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmpmxvBee/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10092)
>           at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmpmxvBee/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12644)
>           at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpmxvBee/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
>           at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpmxvBee/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
>           at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpmxvBee/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)

Is there any way to interact with elements generated by `Java Applet`? How to make those applets elements visible to `Selenium`? There is some alternative to `Selenium` in which I can automate `Java Applets`?

Comment: As exception says selenium found the select box but due to visibility it could not be select...I think this is a HTML select box...you should try `Webdriverwait` to wait until select box visible...let me know if you have any problem...

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I tried to wait for visibility, with no success. I had a similar problem when working with iframe, the error was the same, and I just needed to make selenium switch to frame. In this case however I cant make selenium to focus on the Java applet

Comment: Could you share your website url??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I cant because its a justice system website that requires a custom certificate to login, so you would't be able to visit it

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to interact with elements generated by Java Applet?

no... Selenium can not interact with Java applets.